# How to find timeslot conflict in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, between

I want to find time conflict but it does not give me correct result for below records.
I want to return conflict true for timeslot - "t1.starttime to t2.endtime" as this time slot is conflicted with "t2.starttime and t2.endtime" because 7 to 12 time covered some time of 8 to 11.30.

```
t1.StartTime     t1.EndTime       t2.StartTime     t2.EndTime
---------------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------------
07:00:00.0000000 12:00:00.0000000 08:00:00.0000000 11:30:00.0000000
```

i execute below query but it does not give me result.

```
SELECT 
  count(1) 
FROM 
  t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON

  CAST(t1.StartTime as TIME)  
  BETWEEN CAST(t2.StartTime as TIME) 
  AND CAST(t2.EndTime as TIME) OR CAST(t1.EndTime as TIME)  
  BETWEEN CAST(t2.StartTime as TIME) 
  AND CAST(t2.EndTime as TIME)
```

Comment: Have you searched for: [tsql] or [sql-server] or [sql-server-2008] or [sql-server-2008-r2] or [sql-server-2005] overlapping range

Comment: If you actually try to follow your own query you will notice that 7 is not between 8 and 11:30, and 12 is neither. So of course your condition is not met. See Gordon's answer for the correct logic. What helps usually is to actually take a piece of paper and try to draw your problem with the time periods as lines overlapping. Draw all possible overlaps and see what logical relation you can find between the beginning and ends of each line in each case.

Comment: You should probably read this [article](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct logic for an overlap is a bit simpler:

```
SELECT count(1) 
FROM t1 INNER JOIN
     t2
     ON CAST(t1.StartTime as TIME) < CAST(t2.EndTime as TIME) and
        CAST(t1.EndTime as TIME) > CAST(t2.StartTime as TIME);
```

The logic is that one interval starts before the other ends, and ends after the other starts.

Comment: +1 for the logic of course, but also for not changing the elegant use of a join condition to a `where` as happened in the OP's earlier question :)